# How to add class to a language field?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

In drupal 7 there is a field which displays the node`s language.

I have a multi-site installation and plenty of content types on each of sites. I don`t want to click for hours hiding this field. By default it is generated  with "form-item form-type-item" classes.

How could i add a class to this field to be able to hide it in css?

Thanks

Comment: Please see if this what you need. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19054/add-css-class-to-fields 

If not please provide more details about the field you want to hide. Alternatively, you can hide via Jquery if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but its not the right thing i need. This field is generated by i18n module. It is called language. I can hide it in displays but as i said i am to hide it >100 times. 
It is not the first everywhere or the second.. So it makes harder to find it via css or jQuery..

Comment: Ok i`ve an answer but will submit it in 8 hours )) So the policy says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that in my situation was just adding to node.tpl:

```
hide($content['language']);
```